# Google Analytics User Activity API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to get following google campaign data for the user visiting our website from google analytics and pass the data to another application

- Campaign Content
- Campaign Medium
- Campaign Name
- Campaign Source
- Campaign Term

Found this google analytics API for user activity. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting

Does it provide real time data? Is there another API which we can use to get this information real time for the user based on the google analytics User_ID or Client_ID?

Answer (score 1):

Real-time traffic source information is unavailable via Analytics APIs. Also using APIs for this purpose would be hardly practical because of [API limitations and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas).
You might get some very close results with alternatives like [sourcebuster.js](http://sbjs.rocks/) but note that this wouldn't provide you with Google Ads synced data